# In c# how do I create a list with parameters of a class method

Tags: c#, list, winforms, class

I have been tasked with creating a List<> that will take the information submitted through a windows form app and display them onto a listview. I am required to create a class where the parameters are a string and an int, and feed this information into the list. When I submit the information in the form app, the listview should be filled with the information stored in the list, and sort it by the int value. I have no issue getting the input to the listview but I am confused about how to use the list.

I tried creating a list and feeding it a parameter of my class but I am being thrown an error for the 'type' or 'namespace' not being found.

`List<method> aList = new List<method>;`

Lists are not something that has been covered much in my class so I am unsure what I could do instead to fix this.

This is the code for sending the user input to the list view

```
int index = lvList.Items.Count;
string prio = comboPrio.SelectedItem.ToString();
lvList.Items.Add(txtBox.Text);
lvList.Items[index].SubItems.Add(prio);
```

Comment: First, you are missing the parentheses here: `new List<method>()`. But the error message seems to indicate that the class `method` is not found.

Comment: You need to provide ALL the relevant information. If you're having trouble using your own class, the first thing to do is show us that class. The next thing is to provide the actual error message, verbatim. When people - especially beginners - paraphrase error messages they often leave out critical details. The fact that they don't think they're critical is often the reason they can't solve the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a class for your data:

```
private class ValuePair
    {
        public ValuePair(string stringIn, int intIn)
        {
            string myString = stringIn;
            int myInt = intIn;
        }
    }
```

And then you can create objects of this class and add it to a list:

```
 List<ValuePair> valuePairs = new List<ValuePair>(5);  // create List with initial capacity of 5 items
 ValuePair valuePair = new ValuePair("string1", 27);   // create one item ....
 valuePairs.Add(valuePair);                            // .... and add it to the list
```